# Autocorrecting final sigma

Tags: abbreviations

When writing Greek, sigmas at the ends of words should have a different form. Can I do something automatically to replace: μῖσοσ by μῖσος, and so in all such cases?

Comment: How about running `%s/σ\>/ς/g` whenever you save the file?

Comment: Yes, but it would be better to have it corrected straight away.

Comment: It's even better to *write* it correctly from the start :P You could use (greek) dictionary-based [autocompletion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Dictionary_completions)

Comment: The problem is distinguishing an end-of-word sigma from a normal one. I think you'll have to content yourself with typing some other key combination at the end of word (say `inoremap σ<spac> ς`), then any sigma followed by space will be replaced by the other form. But then you'd have to add another space manually.

Answer (score 1):

Since a final sigma is quickly followed with a space *even if a punctuation marks immediately followf it* (except for the end-of-line case), you could do this: define the folowwing function (in your `~/.vimrc` file) and remap the *space* key in insert mode to this function.

```
" The function checks whether a final greek sigma to be fixed can be found
" on the same line at the left of the cursor; the function should be accessed
" through a mapping of the space key in insert mode (since even punctuation
" marks are flollowed with a space.
function! FixPreviousSigma()
    let l:l = line(".")
    let l:c = col(".")
    let l:s = search('σ\>', 'bcW', l:l)
    if l:s == l:l
        silent execute "normal rς"
    endif
    call cursor(l:l, l:c)
endfunction
```

Then use the tricky mapping whenever you need to use this feature:

```
:inoremap <Space> <ESC>:call FixPreviousSigma()<CR>a<C-v><Space>
```

If you also want to take into account the end-of-line case, maybe you could also try:

```
:inoremap <Enter> <ESC>:callFixPreviousSigma()<CR>o
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but literally my solution has to do with a patch of vim from the last week.Due to some case folding issues vim spell checker was handling all final ς as σ.Now you can normally spellcheck greek words (if you build the latest vim from source at least at patch 8.2.2974).
So here is a guide for that and a good greek dictionary:
Run from wherever

1. `mkdir ~/example_spell`
2. `cd ~/example_spell`
3. `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wooorm/dictionaries/main/dictionaries/el/index.dic`
4. `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wooorm/dictionaries/main/dictionaries/el/index.aff`
5. `vim`
6. in vim command mode type `:mkspell el2 ~/example_spell/index`
7. then exit vim and type : `mkdir ~/.vim/spell`
8. `cp -r ~/example_spell ~/.vim/spell`

Lastly on your file of interest in vim
`:set spell spelllang=el2`
And `z=` over greek words.

All of that thanks to Bram Moolenaar taking the time to learn a greek syntax rule just for the sake of good [software](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/299)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble indeed